# Convert short to VariantType (extract VariantType from short)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need convert short to VariantType

My try (works not correct)

```
VariantType vt = (VariantType)vt;
```

So how can I convert short to VariantType?

(vb.net tag because VariantType is from Microsoft.VisualBasic)

Comment: You probably need the [VarType function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w51ee9c.aspx).

Comment: Fairly confident `VariantType` isn't in C# (If its [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype.aspx))

Comment: It returns short in VariantType ... and I need to extract type definition from short not the type of itself.

Comment: @Sayse Sure it is. Everything in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace is usable from C#.

Comment: @CodyGray - Ah right I completely looked over the name space in the link, thought it was an integral language thing

Comment: What are you trying to do with `vt` once you obtain it? You know that every object has a `GetType()` member method that works basically the same as `VarType`, right?

Comment: @CodyGray my short variable Contains actual VarType and I need to understand which ...

Comment: (not sure why you are looking for that. A conversion from an old VB6 code?) I took a look at the MSDN information and, apparently, you have all what you need there: VariantType/VarType. PS: why I am under the impression that your name is not Heather? :)

Comment: If you explain what you want this exactly for, perhaps someone can propose you an alternative; VarType/VariantType are part of the same reality: you might need to deal with this reality differently or just rely on a different method. PS: I was under the impression that I know you (that's why my comment). Everyone is free to use the nick he/she wants; I use my real name (a short form) but don't think that this is better/worse than any other option. Apparently I don't know you, sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be fine:

The following works perfectly:

```
short num = 4;
VariantType  vt = (VariantType)num;
Console.WriteLine(vt);
```

And outputs "Single". This means that whatever problem you are having is not with the rough line of code you are using.

That having been said the actual line you are using (ie `VariantType vt = (VariantType)vt;` is not going to work because the vt on the right hand side of the equation is invalid since it is unassigned (since you haven't finished declaring it). You should get a "Use of unassigned local vairable 'vt'" when you attempt to compile that.

I'm assuming that the line is a mistake but if not you should explain what you are actually trying to do with that line.

Comment: No, `0x0018` returns `0x0018` for example, and it must be ushort

Comment: 0x18 isn't a valid value for the enum. If you are getting that then there is something wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It's valid according my `WTypes.h`,  `VT_UI2 = 18,` but VariantType enum is really different to VARENUM so I must change the question

Comment: I'm not sure what your WTypes.h is (sounds like a C++ file to me) but it doesn't sound like its right. I used refactor to decompile Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to view the values of the enum and I can guarantee that 0x18 isn't in there. What type do you think it should be?

Comment: If your question is going to change considerably it is probably best to pose it as a new question rather than edit this one and invalidating my answer (since this question might still be useful to somebody else in its current form).

Comment: agreed. Thanks for your response. Gonna ask why VARENUM different to VariantType

Comment: As a brief answer to your other question of why they are different I suspect it is because of the root of the enums. The one in the VB namespace is for compatibility with VB and I suspect mirrors something in VB6. Similarly if the WTypes.h is a C++ header it is probably just that there is no standard and so they both decided to do things differently (possibly also because they may have different types as well and thus by necessity be different).